# Creating functions with formulas in excel in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm trying to create a function that calculates Drawdown.
It would work as follows:

1. I have a series of quotes for a specific stock in column B: B (example)
2. I want to know the maximum drawdown, that is, how much would be the biggest decrease in the quote.
   [image]

In this case the biggest indentation occurs in the yellow area!that is, the formula would look like: Drawdown = (MaxValue/Value)-1  ==>   Drawdown = (13/9)-1

I tried as follows, with no result:

```
Public Function MDD(ByVal Selection0, ByVal Selection1)
    'Function Max DrawDown

    Dim i As Long
    Dim Drawdown0 As Long
    Dim Drawdown1 As Long
    
    i = 2
    
    Drawdown0 = "(" & Selection0 & "/MAX(" & Selection1 & ")) - 1"


    
    While i < Plan1.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Drawdown1 = "(" & Selection0 & "/MAX(" & Selection1 & ")) - 1"
        If Drawdown1 > Drawdown0 Then
            Drawdown0 = Drawdown1
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Wend
   
   MDD = Drawdown0
End Function

Sub lsMDD()
    Application.MacroOptions Macro:="MDD", Category:=4
End Sub
```

Where's the error?

Comment: It seems like you are conflating formulas and VBA.... `Drawdown0 = "(" & Selection0 & "/MAX(" & Selection1 & ")) - 1"` is trying to assign a string (text) to a `Long`.

Comment: @BigBen I need to use a formula to calculate or retrieve the maximum between the arranged values ​​... In this case, I am unsure how to do it.

Comment: `Application.Max` might be helpful. You have to actually translate the formula logic to VBA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to iterate over the range. Look at Application.[WorksheetFunction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction) - it's got everything you need.

```
Public Function MDD(ByVal pRange As Variant) As Variant
    MDD = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(pRange) / Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(pRange) - 1
End Function
```

Comment: MDD takes one argument, pRange, which is the range covering your source data, say A1:A10. Application.WorksheetFunction exposes many Excel worksheet functions to VBA. Here I just used WorksheetFunction's Max and Min to do the same as formula "=MAX(A1:10)/MIN(A1:A10)-1" would have done on the worksheet.

Comment: Great! Thank you! I will study how 'Application' functions (Previously: Worked perfectly! Could you please explain to me how this function works, if you are not asking too much?) Sorry...edited